# Svn -> git migration with several trunk/branches/tags

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have a single SVN repository with the following **current** structure:

- project1

  - branches
  - trunk
  - tags
- project2

  - branches
  - trunk
  - tags

which **originally** had this structure:

- project

  - branches
  - trunk

    - proj1
    - proj2
  - tags

That is, the project was split into two separate "subrepositories" (or whatever you want to call that)

Is there any way to migrate this to git **without losing history**?
Would svn2git be better that git-svn for this scenario? Is there any other migration tool?

**EDIT**: I tried git svn clone as suggested but, as I thought, it didn't follow the move from the old structure to the new one. It only imported the revisions from the new structure.

Comment: If `git-svn` doesn’t “get” the old structure you already screwed up creating the current structure because `git-svn` *does* follow history to the first revision.

Comment: @Bombe: yeah, I think the same... I think I have a workaround, will post it here if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I converted the main trunk to git:

```
git svn clone url-to-project -s
```

Then I converted each project:

```
git svn clone url-to-project1 -s
git svn clone url-to-project2 -s
...
```

Then for each project I attached the previous history from the main trunk using grafts and filter-branch.

I just [blogged about it](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/03/stitching-git-histories.html).

Answer (score 1):

svn2git just uses "git svn" underneath, so it won't be "better" per se. It just makes nice tags and branches and cleans things up for a clean break from svn. If that's what you want, I'd go ahead and use it on the two sub-repositories individually. It will get all of the appropriate history.

Comment: didn't know that svn2git used git-svn... however git-svn didn't follow the move from the old structure to the new one :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the built-in

```
git svn clone
```

[git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

Comment: didn't follow the move from the old structure to the new one :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your "current" structure already has all the history from the previous structure. So, cloning each project using [`git svn clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) should work fine.

There won't be any need to tell Git about the previous structure with multiple projects under the trunk directory.

The great thing about Git is that you can try the migration as many times as you like until you're satisfied with the outcome.

Comment: git-svn didn't follow the move from the old structure to the new one :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use `git svn clone -s SVN_REPOS` to have git clone the Subversion repository assuming a standard Subversion layout.  You will get a local git branch called master, but `git branch -a` will show you all the remote branches.  Subversion branches will just have the branch name, but tags will have a branch name of `tags/tag_name`.

Don't reuse branch/tag names when cloning locally!  git doesn't like that.

This guide helped me a lot.

http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/

Comment: it didn't follow the move from the old structure to the new one :-(