# git-svn and huge svn repository with many "sub-repositories"

Tags: git, svn

I'd like to use git-svn in my company for certain project "proj1".

However our repository looks like this:

```
proj1/
  app1/
    component1/
      branches/
      tags/
      trunk/
    component2/
      branches/
      tags/
      trunk/
  app2/
    component22/
      branches/
      tags/
      trunk/
```

How would you cope with this?

I thought git submodules is the answer but I don't know much about it and from googling it seems it isn't supported by git-svn.

Thank you.

EDIT: This question is related [Svn -> git migration with several trunk/branches/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540496/svn-git-migration-with-several-trunk-branches-tags). There is no correct answer though. The highest ranked one expects that there are few"sub-repositories". However in our project there are a lot of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual practice is to associate a [component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735) (a [coherent set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896944/component-based-web-project-directory-layout-with-git-and-symlinks) with its [own development lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321818/structuring-related-components-in-git/7322295#7322295)) to a git repo.
That means you can make several `git-svn clone`, each one with a SVN address referencing a distinct component.

From there, you can reference those various repos within a single parent repo as [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194) if you want.
But the idea remains: once you are within one of those submodules, you are actually within a git repo: that repo will support `git-svn dcommit` operations.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. Do you know about any script that can automate it (eg. walk through SVN repository, detect "sub-repos", doing "git svn clone" and adding submodule) ?

Comment: @woky no, because a directory in SVN can represent... anything (tag, branch, app, component, module, ...). In your case, a component is a directory with `branches`, `tag` and `trunk` within it, so it shouldn't be too hard to script.