# SVN -> Git migration with structure variations

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I, currently, have the following SVN structure:

- project1

  - branches
  - trunk
  - tags
- project2

  - branches
  - trunk
  - tags
- muchMoreStuff

  - branches
  - trunk
  - tags

which **originally** had this structure:

- project

  - branches
  - trunk

    - proj1
    - proj2
    - moreStuff
    - muchMore
  - tags

I'm trying to get independent Git repositories, one for "Project 1" and another for "Project 2".

The issue is different but similar than this another SO question: [Svn -> git migration with several trunk/branches/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540496/svn-git-migration-with-several-trunk-branches-tags)

A git svn clone operation only imports from "SVN head" to the structure refactor.

I need to avoid migrating the full first part of the history since my svn repo is huge, I tried it but it takes days and GIT usually crashes with an outOfMemory exception.

Is there a way to track the svn move/structure refactor operation and get the full "Project N" history avoiding the rest?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40505929/4328594) might be of some help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do a one-time conversion (opposed to using Git as frontend while still keeping the SVN server in the background) you shouldn't use git-svn.

Better use a proper migration tool, there are several out there and several are named svn2git. I have made very good experiences with this one: http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/MoveToGit/UsingSvn2Git You can virtually do anything you want, except of having paths land in two result repositories with one run, but with two separate runs even this is possible.

If you want to analyze your historical structure first to make sure there were really no other layout before your knowledge, you might want to use svneverever from this Blog entry first: http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763, this very much helped me in SVN to Git transitions of Repositories I didn't know from the start.